# setting Installation path during installation

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am using visual studio 2010 to create an installer for my application. I want my application to be installed in C:\ApplicationName (if it already exists), if this folder does not exits then it should be installed in c:\Manufacturer\ApplicationName . I was not sure if i could achieve this by using a costume action as by the time the costume action was called the installation path has been already set.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/09/20/472125.aspx) describes how to achive what you want. The only differece is that instead of a RegLocator you can use a [DrLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check if the folder exists.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply. I actually followed the steps but still it seems my prob exists. There is a chance that I might be missing sth as i am not much familiar with Orca tool. bellow is what i did:1- Created a new entry in the AppSearch table with Signature_ =ApplicationName and Property name=NAME

Comment: You should also populate the DrLocator table.

Comment: 2-Created an entry in the RegLocator table with Signature_=ApplicationName  and path=c:\ 3- Created an entry in the CustomAction table that has a action name=TEST, Target value=[NAME], source name=TARGETDIR, type=307(not sure about it) 4-Add an entry to the InstallExecuteSequence table that with Action column name=TEST,Condition=NAME and i did not set any sequence number  . It is worth mentioning the application install directory in vs installer is set to c:\Manufacturer\ApplicationName. however saving orc, the app was installed in c:\Manufacturer\ApplicationName. any hint much appreciated!

Comment: 2-I think you mean DrLocator here. You should set the Path column to

Comment: yes sorry i meant DrLocator. I did not get what should i set path column to from your previous reply

Comment: 2- Set the path Path column to [WindowsVolume][ProductName] 3 - Change the type to 51 4 - Give it a sequence number before CostInitialize.

Comment: Also for better debugging create an installation log and monitor the change of TAGRETDIR property

Comment: following the steps, i noticed that the files which are located directly in Application Folder (in File System) are installed in [WindowsVolume][ProductName] and file which reside inside a folder in Application Folder are installed in defaultlocation [WindowsVolume][Manufacturer]\[ProductName] and this is the path which is displayed during installation. to give more info I set sequence number=799 (CostInitialize=800) in step 4 .

Comment: this is a part of log file: Action start 15:37:08: CostFinalize.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [15:37:08:451]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Condition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [15:37:08:454]: Target path resolution complete. Dumping Directory table...
MSI (s) (58:6C) [15:37:08:454]: Note: target paths subject to change (via custom actions or browsing)
MSI (s) (58:6C) [15:37:08:454]: Dir (target): Key: TARGETDIR , Object: C:\ProductName\
MSI (s) (58:6C) [15:37:08:454]: Dir (target): Key: _68566083948749A8B470EDA8580ACB2D , Object: C:\Manufacturer\ProductName\A\